# WPF performance issue. Bindings ?

Tags: wpf, performance, binding

We have a financial application that we have started to develop 5 years ago. It is a migration of an old application with the main purpose being to achieve a nice user interface.
Because of UI considerations back then the chosen technology is WPF. The application still uses .Net version 3.5 with SP1.
The current application is a layered one, but the business logic and the back-end is different technology and it is outside the scope of our problem.
The client is not a traditional MVVM application, however it mixes some concepts from it.

In a simple scenario data is retrieved from an application server in the form of typed datasets. The datasets being to the client are mapped into data objects (POCO) implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, the properties raising the PropertyChanged event.
Those data objects are practically bound to the UI and as response to user interaction some routed commands are executed so in the end data is retrieved from the server.
A variation of Active Record pattern is implemented so basically each table from a dataset received from the server gets mapped into a data object, a property from a data object representing a column from a table and a data object instance represents a row from the table.
Because of the WPF bindings used the retrieved data automatically appears on the UI.

The problem is that we started to have performance problems. They appear sometimes in a non-deterministic fashion after the data is retrieved from the server. There is a delay between the moment the mapping from the datasets starts until the UI is updated.
This delays on slow machines can go up to a couple of seconds.
On powerful machines the delays seem to be insignificant. Also the delays are not constant, so retrieving the same data the UI is updated sometimes in a couple of milliseconds and sometimes it can last seconds.

We think we have isolated the problem and it is the usage of bindings in cases where a binding source (data object) has many properties (ex: 50) and the UI contains many controls (text boxes) that use bindings. 
Some measurements have been made also using different tools. It seems there are no memory leaks. The processing delays were seen at the moment a property of a data object participating in a binding is updated. 
Also seems like the duration of setting the value of the property depends also on the value itself (ex: updating decimal properties with the zero value is faster, using or not converters on the binding, tests were made also without converters and strings, the property value string “0” is updated much faster than property value “123.456.00”).

So basically we think that a major part of the performance issue is using many controls on the UI (ex: 150 textboxes) bound to objects having many properties (ex: 50). We have noticed that targeting the 3.5 version is much slower than targeting the version 4.0 or 4.5. 
Delays can be reproduced but they are not occurring all the time. The delays increase or decrease exponentially like from 5 milliseconds to 2 seconds or on very slow machines even up to tens of seconds.

We suspect the performance issue (delay until the UI is updated) is related to the WPF technology and the binding mechanism but it is not confirmed.

**So basically we do not understand why the delays appear, why they appear only sometimes (non-deterministic) and if they are because of the WPF binding system!**

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say that you have taken measurements, but it sounds like you may not have used the correct tools. In this case, you need to use a profiler: it will tell you exactly which methods are eating up CPU time (assuming you're not actually I/O constrained) and then you can confirm or reject your binding hypothesis (which is certainly a *plausible* one.) Also, the somewhat random, stuttered nature of the slowdowns *may* be an indication that a garbage collection is occuring. Again, profile it and see.

Comment: If you have been able to isolate the problem, then post a sample application demonstrating it. We have a BIG Line-of-Business in WPF 4.0 and had NEVER had anything like this. Our application works like a charm and data / UI updates are immediate.

Comment: Your observation of the difference between 3.5 and 4.0+ alone tells you that there were performance issues in 3.5 that were remedied in later versions.

Comment: Measurements have been made using Red Gate memory and performance profiler. Also the performance counters related to .Net data do not seem to indicate a garbage collection issue. Also there seems to be a randomness in the methods giving the processing delays. Sometimes there are internal .Net methods related to the Dispatcher or to text change of the textbox or methods related to CommandManager requery invalidations. Also the randomness does not happen once in a while it happens in response to user interaction (ex: clicking on a button) like two times from five.

Comment: Regarding HighCore's response I would like to ask him if the machines on which they are running the app are powerful ones or they run like a charm on less powerful machines also. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In order to be up to date with the findings. Seems like multiple textbox bindings have a poor performance on relatively slow machines. Thanks to **Radu**'s suggestion who helped us a lot, we have changed the text boxes in critical scenarios to a special textblock which shows and hides a textbox, creates its binding to the text on the fly on focus and mouse events. So basically the textboxes were changed to textblocks and only one textbox is visible and bound when focus is in the specific control.